# unable to activate developer's mode on infinix m8

Tags: android

I am a trainee android developer who needed to activate developer's mode and USB debugging on my Infinix m8. The option("Build Number") is either hidden or unavailable in "About Device" under "Settings". I need help on how to either make the option visible or activate developer's mode without Build Number. Thank you.

Comment: Many phones have an extra menu under "About" called something similar to "Software Information," and that's where the build number is listed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, "About device" is the last option listed and there are no options like "Software Information".

Comment: By "under" I meant "inside" the About menu.

Comment: "Software Information" is not included inside "About device", the last option inside "About device" is "Build Time". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

USB Debugging has already been activated on the phone. The option to do that is not available under About Phone.

Answer (score -1):

How to open Developer Options in INFINIX Zero 4 X555:

1. The device must be turned on, so hold down the Power key for a short while.
2. In the next step from Main Menu find and select Settings and open About device.
3. Then tap 7 times in Build number to become a developer.

Excellent! You have just activated the Developer Options.